# Unable to fetch scan response from dynamodb through a script in gitlab cicd

Tags: gitlab, amazon-dynamodb, devops, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a project in gitlab which has a script called dockerRun.sh that runs in a docker container. This script interacts with dynamodb and fetches data.

Below is the snippet from dockerRun.sh which fetches data from dynamodb table

```
cycleId=$(aws dynamodb scan --table-name cycle_info --filter-expression "isLatest = :a" --projection-expression 'cycleId' --expression-attribute-values '{":a":{"S":"true"}}')
```

Results is :

```
In getCycleId function
retrieving latest AIXM CycleId from dynamodb
None    1   2
CYCLEID 1911.191024
```

Now, I have another project in gitlab and in this project's cicd pipeline I have added a stage where I am calling the same dockerRun.sh from the previous project mentioned.  While I run this pipeline and when the dockerRun.sh gets executed this time dynamodb fetch gives an error which is :

```
An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the Scan operation: Requested resource not found
```

I have cross checked that the data is present in the database.

So the summary is both time same script is running but while accessing it from another project it does not fetches result. Can somebody help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the other project has the right AWS credentials to access the account that has the DynamoDB table

Comment: Yes it does has the same credentials for which it is giving results in first project